# How to replace or append object to another object using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 2 objects

```
{
    "Simon": { 
        "occupation": "garbage man",
        "age": "21"
    }
}
```

and this one

```
{
    "wife": "Kate"
}
```

How will I insert the second object to the first object to result as

```
{
    "Simon": { 
        "occupation": "garbage man",
        "age": "21",
        "wife": "Kate"
    }
}
```

And also can be applied even when wife exists:

```
{
    "wife": "Shandia"
}
```

Results to

```
{
    "Simon": { 
        "occupation": "garbage man",
        "age": "21",
        "wife": "Shandia"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using lodash?

Comment: Why Lodash? Just `Object.assign`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash for it. Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to do that in plain JS. It works for the second case as well.

And if you really want to do it with lodash, use `_.assign`; it works the same.

```js
var simon = {
  "Simon": {
    "occupation": "garbage man",
    "age": "21"
  }
}

var wife = {
  "wife": "Shandia"
};

Object.assign(simon.Simon, wife);
console.log(simon);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Very short and concise.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, if you prefer to not change the original object (immutable way), you can use ES6 spread operator.

```js
var simon = {
  "Simon": {
    "occupation": "garbage man",
    "age": "21"
  }
}

var wife = {
  "wife": "Shandia"
};

const simonWithWife = {
  Simon: {
    ...simon.Simon,
    ...wife
  }
}

console.log(simon); // doesn't get changed
console.log(simonWithWife);
```

Comment: `Object.assign` and `_.assign` already support doing this without mutating the original object.